# Why $\mathbb{P}(X\geq u) \leq e^{-u}$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, poisson-distribution

Let $X \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$. Chernoff bounds provide us, for exemple, $\mathbb{P}(X\geq 3 \lambda) \leq e^{-\lambda}$. I would like to get something like $\mathbb{P}(X\geq u) \leq e^{-u}$ or, more generally, $\mathbb{P}(X\geq u) \leq Ce^{-Ku}$, for every $u \geq 3\lambda$. (The positive constants $C$ and $K$ are not important in this case, since my goal is to take the limit when $u$ tends to infinity and show that this probability decays exponentially to zero.)

$\textbf{My idea:}$

Let $u=3x\lambda$, for $x \geq 1$. Define $Y \sim \text{Poisson}(x \lambda)$. Then

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X>u) \leq \mathbb{P}(Y>u) \leq e^{-x \lambda}=e^{-\frac{u}{3}}.
\end{equation}

So, if $x \to \infty$ then $u \to \infty$, and I get what I want.

Is that good? I think there may be a better justification.

I appreciate any help or suggestion

Comment: The Chernov bound says that for any $r>0$ we have $$P[X \geq u] \leq E[e^{rX}]e^{-ru} \quad \forall u \in \mathbb{R}$$ You can compute $E[e^{rX}]$ when $X$ is a Poisson variable.  It is finite for all $r>0$, including $r=1$.

Comment: Great! When $X$ is a Poisson variable we have, for $r>0$, $\mathbb{E}[e^{rX}] = e^{\lambda(e^r-1)}$. Then, for $r=1$, it follows that $\mathbb{P}\left[ X \geq u\right] = e^{\lambda(e-1)}e^{-u} \leq e^{\lambda e} e^{-u}$.  It's OK? Thak you for your help!

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  This gives an exponentially-decaying upper bound.  In fact the true rate of vanishing is faster than exponential.